# I can add to ::oo::define to add global tclOO class definition extensions, how can I do this non-globally?

Tags: class, tcl

I have found some TclOO resources that mention you can create subclasses of `::oo::class`. You can also create bare objects using `::oo::object create`, but you cannot migrate from a bare class to a real class (ie parent `oo::object` to parent `oo::class`)

I'm looking to create a DSL for defining modules, that just creates class definitions.

```
module create mysql 5.5 {
  executable mysqld
  method post_install { ... }
}

module create redis 2.6 {
  executable redis-server
  ...
}
```

These could then be used as

```
set mod [mysql new]
$mod install
$mod post_install
```

Comment: You can't change non-classes into classes or _vice versa_ (because they've got different C structures underlying them) and `oo::object` and `oo::class` themselves have fixed relationships — everything else depends on them! — but apart from those sanity-enforcing restrictions, you can change things around substantially. Some things you can do are probably ill-advised, but the option is there if you need it…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can't make class-specific extension commands directly in the `oo::define` system, you can do the next-best-thing very easily. The trick is to use `namespace path` to profile-in the additional commands to the namespace just for the duration of the definition processing. Which is somewhat over-fancy way of saying that it's pretty easy in metaclass constructors to do this sort of stuff:

```
# First, build the definition of the extensions
namespace eval ::ModuleDefineExtensions {
    proc executable {program} {
        # I'm not quite sure how you want to handle this, but [uplevel] and
        # [info level] will reveal what you need.
        puts "define executable as $program here"
    }
}

# Now, the [module] metaclass
oo::class create module {
    superclass oo::class
    constructor {definitionScript} {
        # Save the old path
        set oldpath [namespace eval ::oo::define {namespace path}]

        # Set the new one
        namespace eval ::oo::define {namespace path ::ModuleDefineExtensions}

        # Now let the superclass constructor handle this, trapping errors
        catch {next $definitionScript} msg opt

        # Restore the old path
        namespace eval ::oo::define [list namespace path $oldpath]

        # Rethrow any errors
        return -options $opt $msg
    }
}
```

You probably need some more bits and pieces (e.g., a suitable default superclass of module classes that defines common methods) but those are conventional.

---

If you're using 8.6, the `module` definition can be simpler (this time without comments):

```
oo::class create module {
    superclass oo::class
    constructor {definitionScript} {
        set oldpath [namespace eval ::oo::define {namespace path}]
        namespace eval ::oo::define {namespace path ::ModuleDefineExtensions}
        try {
            next $definitionScript
        } finally {
            namespace eval ::oo::define [list namespace path $oldpath]
        }
    }
}
```

It's the same in principle, but uses the try/finally command of 8.6.